# Finding MAVEN inside Jenkins from an ANT task

Tags: maven, ant, jenkins

I have a bit of a situation going on...

My ANT build script calls maven and I need this to be working inside Jenkins but I have no idea how to tell jenkins where maven executable is short of hard-coding the path.

I cannot change any of these procedures I just need to find out if there's some sort of env variable that jenkins exports that I could use..

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you not reference the Maven executable via the $M2_HOME environment variable as follows "${env.M2_HOME}/bin/mvn". This assumes that Maven has been installed normally on the Jenkins server. Another option is to pass in the path as a command line property to ANT and let the jenkins job tell you where the Maven executable is: "${m2.home}/bin/mvn"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for Maven based builds and I believe it should work for Ant too:

On your configuration file(XML): use **${variable-name}**

On Jenkins: Job -> Configuration -> Build -> Goals and options -> use: **-Dvariable-name=value**

Regards.

Comment: Where "value" would be your Maven path address